# Cannot submit to page if $_POST is not empty

Tags: php, forms, wordpress, http-post

I have a custom wordpress template page that acts as a login for a support area. I want the form to submit to the same page, the page is http:///supportarea. If I submit the form without any values I get the appropriate response from the page (or rather from my PHP functions) but the weird thing is if I submit it the same page **with** post values I get a 404 error.

Can anyone shed some light on this please?

**UPDATE:** If the form action points to the real location of the file it works but the url looks bad but doesn't seem to work on it's wordpress pretty URL with post values

```
action="/wp-content/themes/perceptive/supportarea/index.php"
```

Without form values:
[image]

With form values: 
[image]

The response in FF:
[image]

Comment: if you don't show any code, it's really hard. I mean, as an example:  Maybe you get redirected if all values are correct, and the page you get redirected doesn't exist? Maybe you have some javascript that 'catches' filled-in forms and sends it to another page? Maybe you have a freaky javascrip that changes the button as soon as you type something to redirect you to `/404page.doesntexist`. :)

Comment: It doesn't even reach my PHP functions I echo'd and `exit;`'d but nothing. Possibly could be javascript. I have tried turning `RewriteEngine` to off in a htaccess file in that particular directory but still nothing :/

Comment: @Nanne If the form action points to the real location of the file it works but the url looks bad but doesn't seem to work on it's wordpress pretty URL with post values

`action="/wp-content/themes/perceptive/supportarea/index.php"`

Comment: ¿Have you tried `action=""` or `action= "<?php PHP_SELF ?>"` instead of the relative path?

Comment: Is the data being sent as POST or GET? If the form's method is set incorrectly, then it would explain why the page works without variables. If you have some rewrite rules enabled, then it could try to load a non-existent page.

Comment: @faa Thanks for the suggestions but I tried both of those with resulting 404 errors :/

Comment: As Nanne pointed out. More information is needed (The relevant code), otherwise it is only guesswork. Try to include it in your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is any of your POST variables named "name"? Wordpress has weird bug that it gives 404 when there is variable "name" inside POST.

Comment: Yes they are I'll check the existence of that bug now.